# Grouped result in recursive query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a recursive query that is working as intended for calculating weighted average cost for inventory calculation. My problem is that I need multiple weighted average from the same query grouped by different columns. I know I can solve the issue by calculating it multiple times, one for each key-column. But because of query performance considerations, I want it to be traversed once. Sometimes I have 1M+ rows.

I have simplified the data and replaced weighted average to a simple sum to make my problem more easy to follow.

How can I get the result below using recursive cte? Remember that I have to use a recursive query to calculate weighted average cost. I am on sql server 2016.

Example data (Id is also the sort order. The Id and Key is unique together.)

```
Id  Key1  Key2  Key3  Value
1   1     1     1     10
2   1     1     1     10
3   1     2     1     10
4   2     2     1     10
5   1     2     1     10
6   1     1     2     10
7   1     1     1     10
8   3     3     1     10
```

Expected result

```
Id  Key1  Key2  Key3  Value  Key1Sum  Key2Sum  Key3Sum
1   1     1     1     10     10       10       10
2   1     1     1     10     20       20       20
3   1     2     1     10     30       10       30
4   2     2     1     10     10       20       40
5   1     2     1     10     40       30       50
6   1     1     2     10     50       30       10
7   1     1     1     10     60       40       60
8   3     3     1     10     10       10       70
```

**EDIT**

After some well deserved criticism I have to be much better in how I make a question.

Here is an example and why I need a recursive query. In the example I get the result for Key1, but I need it for Key2 and Key3 as well in the same query. I know that I can repeat the same query three times, but that is not preferable.

```
DECLARE @InventoryItem AS TABLE (
    IntentoryItemId INT NULL,
    InventoryOrder INT,
    Key1 INT NULL,
    Key2 INT NULL,
    Key3 INT NULL,
    Quantity NUMERIC(22,9) NOT NULL,
    Price NUMERIC(16,9) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @InventoryItem (
    IntentoryItemId,
    InventoryOrder,
    Key1,
    Key2,
    Key3,
    Quantity,
    Price
)
VALUES 
(1, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1),
(2, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2),
(3, NULL, 1, 2, 1, 10, 2),
(4, NULL, 2, 2, 1, 10, 1),
(5, NULL, 1, 2, 1, 10, 5),
(6, NULL, 1, 1, 2, 10, 3),
(7, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 10, 3),
(8, NULL, 3, 3, 1, 10, 1);


--The steps below will give me the cost "grouped" by Key1
WITH Key1RowNumber AS (
    SELECT 
        IntentoryItemId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY IntentoryItemId) AS RowNumber
    FROM @InventoryItem
)

UPDATE @InventoryItem
    SET InventoryOrder = Key1RowNumber.RowNumber
FROM @InventoryItem InventoryItem
INNER JOIN Key1RowNumber
ON Key1RowNumber.IntentoryItemId = InventoryItem.IntentoryItemId;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  
        IntentoryItemId,
        InventoryOrder,
        Key1,
        Quantity,
        Price,
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9), InventoryItem.Quantity) AS CurrentQuantity,
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9), (InventoryItem.Quantity * InventoryItem.Price) / NULLIF(InventoryItem.Quantity, 0)) AS AvgPrice
    FROM @InventoryItem InventoryItem
    WHERE InventoryItem.InventoryOrder = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        Sub.IntentoryItemId,
        Sub.InventoryOrder,
        Sub.Key1,
        Sub.Quantity,
        Sub.Price,
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9), Main.CurrentQuantity + Sub.Quantity) AS CurrentQuantity,
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),
                ((Main.CurrentQuantity) * Main.AvgPrice + Sub.Quantity * Sub.price)
                    / 
                NULLIF((Main.CurrentQuantity)  + Sub.Quantity, 0) 
        ) AS AvgPrice
    FROM CTE Main
    INNER JOIN @InventoryItem Sub 
    ON Main.Key1 = Sub.Key1
    AND Sub.InventoryOrder = main.InventoryOrder + 1
)

SELECT cte.IntentoryItemId, cte.AvgPrice
FROM cte
ORDER BY IntentoryItemId
```

Comment: What have you tried? That is, where are you lost?  Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later, you're likely to get better performance using windowing functions than recursion.

Comment: check my  latest answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why you will want to calculate on 1M+ rows ?

Secondly I think your db design is wrong ? `key1 ,key2,key3` should have been `unpivoted` and one column called `Keys` and 1 more column to identify each key group.

It will be clear to you in below example.

If I am able to optimize my query then I can think of calculating many rows else I try to limit number of rows.

Also if possible you can think of keeping calculated column of Avg Price.i.e. when table is populated then you can calculate and store it.

First let us know, if output is correct or not.

```
DECLARE @InventoryItem AS TABLE (
    IntentoryItemId INT NULL,
    InventoryOrder INT,
    Key1 INT NULL,
    Key2 INT NULL,
    Key3 INT NULL,
    Quantity NUMERIC(22,9) NOT NULL,
    Price NUMERIC(16,9) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @InventoryItem (
    IntentoryItemId,
    InventoryOrder,
    Key1,
    Key2,
    Key3,
    Quantity,
    Price
)
VALUES 
(1, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1),
(2, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2),
(3, NULL, 1, 2, 1, 10, 2),
(4, NULL, 2, 2, 1, 10, 1),
(5, NULL, 1, 2, 1, 10, 5),
(6, NULL, 1, 1, 2, 10, 3),
(7, NULL, 1, 1, 1, 10, 3),
(8, NULL, 3, 3, 1, 10, 1);
--select * from @InventoryItem
--return    
;with cte as
(
select * 
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY IntentoryItemId) AS rn1
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key2 ORDER BY IntentoryItemId) AS rn2
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key3 ORDER BY IntentoryItemId) AS rn3
from @InventoryItem
)
,cte1 AS (
       SELECT  
        IntentoryItemId,

        Key1 keys,
        Quantity,
        Price
        ,rn1 
        ,rn1 rn
        ,1 pk
    FROM cte c

   union ALL

   SELECT  
        IntentoryItemId,

        Key2 keys,
        Quantity,
        Price
        ,rn1 
        ,rn2 rn
        ,2 pk
    FROM cte c

     union ALL

   SELECT  
        IntentoryItemId,

        Key3 keys,
        Quantity,
        Price
        ,rn1 
        ,rn3 rn
        ,3 pk
    FROM cte c

)

, cte2 AS (
    SELECT  
        IntentoryItemId,
       rn,
        Keys,
        Quantity,
        Price,
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9), InventoryItem.Quantity) AS CurrentQuantity,
         CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9), (InventoryItem.Quantity * InventoryItem.Price)) a,
          CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),  InventoryItem.Price) b,

        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9), (InventoryItem.Quantity * InventoryItem.Price) / NULLIF(InventoryItem.Quantity, 0)) AS AvgPrice
        ,pk
    FROM cte1 InventoryItem
    WHERE InventoryItem.rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        Sub.IntentoryItemId,
       sub.rn,
        Sub.Keys,
        Sub.Quantity,
        Sub.Price,
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9), Main.CurrentQuantity + Sub.Quantity) AS CurrentQuantity,
         CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),Main.CurrentQuantity * Main.AvgPrice),
         CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),Sub.Quantity * Sub.price),

        CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),
                ((Main.CurrentQuantity * Main.AvgPrice) + (Sub.Quantity * Sub.price))
                    / 
                NULLIF(((Main.CurrentQuantity)  + Sub.Quantity), 0) 
        ) AS AvgPrice
        ,sub.pk
    FROM CTE2 Main
    INNER JOIN cte1 Sub 
    ON Main.Keys = Sub.Keys and main.pk=sub.pk
    AND Sub.rn = main.rn + 1
    --and Sub.InventoryOrder<=2
)
select * 
,(select AvgPrice from cte2 c1 where pk=2 and c1.IntentoryItemId=c.IntentoryItemId ) AvgPrice2
,(select AvgPrice from cte2 c1 where pk=2 and c1.IntentoryItemId=c.IntentoryItemId ) AvgPrice3
from cte2 c

where pk=1
ORDER BY pk,rn
```

> Alternate Solution (for Sql 2012+) and many thanks to Jason,

```
SELECT *
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),avg((Quantity * Price) / NULLIF(Quantity, 0)) 
OVER(PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER by IntentoryItemId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))AvgKey1Price
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),avg((Quantity * Price) / NULLIF(Quantity, 0)) 
OVER(PARTITION BY Key2 ORDER by IntentoryItemId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))AvgKey2Price
,CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,9),avg((Quantity * Price) / NULLIF(Quantity, 0)) 
OVER(PARTITION BY Key3 ORDER by IntentoryItemId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))AvgKey3Price
from @InventoryItem
order by IntentoryItemId
```

Comment: 1M+ because my manager is not fond of persisting calculated data to have an edge against others. I will go for your answer, because as you say it is probably best to change the preparation of data instead of trying to calculate it all simultaneously. I had a dream that I could do this in fewer iterations because the recursive operation is quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in SQL Server 2012 & later...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Id INT,
    Key1 INT,
    Key2 INT,  
    Key3 INT,
    [Value] INT 
    );
INSERT #TestData(Id, Key1, Key2, Key3, Value) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 10), 
    (2, 1, 1, 1, 10), 
    (3, 1, 2, 1, 10), 
    (4, 2, 2, 1, 10), 
    (5, 1, 2, 1, 10), 
    (6, 1, 1, 2, 10), 
    (7, 1, 1, 1, 10), 
    (8, 3, 3, 1, 10);

--=============================================================

SELECT 
    td.Id, td.Key1, td.Key2, td.Key3, td.Value,
    Key1Sum = SUM(td.[Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY td.Key1 ORDER BY td.Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
    Key2Sum = SUM(td.[Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY td.Key2 ORDER BY td.Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING),
    Key3Sum = SUM(td.[Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY td.Key3 ORDER BY td.Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
    #TestData td
ORDER BY
    td.Id;
```

results...

```
Id          Key1        Key2        Key3        Value       Key1Sum     Key2Sum     Key3Sum
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1           1           10          10          10          10
2           1           1           1           10          20          20          20
3           1           2           1           10          30          10          30
4           2           2           1           10          10          20          40
5           1           2           1           10          40          30          50
6           1           1           2           10          50          30          10
7           1           1           1           10          60          40          60
8           3           3           1           10          10          10          70
```

Comment: Thanks, but I simplified the original question and that led to some misunderstanding of what my problem was. Now I have updated the question with an example that show why I use/need recursion.